# Picking out dates from string via regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_match` to pick out two dates from a string (I can't guarantee the string will always be the same, but it will always contain two British dates).  An example:

```
$row['status'] = "Client updated: renewal date changed from 31/01/2015 to 21/02/2015";
```

The regular expression I'm using worked in an online Regex tester, but I keep getting PHP errors when using it with `preg_match`.

The initial error: `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

When I try to change it I get errors like: `Unknown modifier '\'`

I'm not great with regex, so any help will be apperciated.

```
$matches = array();
$pattern= '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}';
preg_match($pattern, $row['status'], $matches);
```

Comment: Use a delimiter that doesn't occur inside your regex pattern, for example: `#`, `~`, `%` etc.

Comment: Enclose the pattern with slash (/)
/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}/

Comment: @Amal at the moment, there's no delimiter being used at all!

Comment: @TomFenech: I know. But the OP tried to use `/`, which generated the error "*Unknown modifier '\'*". That is because the pattern itself contains a forward slash. To avoid the error message, you need to use a delimiter that doesn't occur inside the pattern, or escape *all* the occurrences of the delimiter properly.

Comment: @noia_0328: If you're going to use a forward slash as the delimiter, you'll have to escape it inside the regex pattern, like so: `'/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/'`. The pattern in your comment would still generate the "*Unknown Modifier*" error message.

Comment: Yeah, as what @AmalMurali suggested, you may instead use %,# since you are already using / or escape it on your pattern.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the advice, adding a delimiter to the beginning and end gets me pass the error, but it's only picking out 1 date, not two?

Comment: Try to use preg_match_all to capture all matches

Comment: cheers @noia_0328, that's done it, guess I just assumed it would already do that, given it outputs an array.  Thanks everyone